# Need help in VS code with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I need to use 'ng serve' to run something but when I try to do sudo npm install I get this error:

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

audited 1499 packages in 15.548s

52 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 319 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Anyone know what to do so ng serve can work? when I try ng serve right now it says command not found.

Comment: Those aren't errors. Your problem is that `ng` isn't installed.

Comment: Error message is pretty much self self-explanatory. Bootstrap require jquery and popper.js to work and you are missing both of those. First try npm install jquery and popperjs

Answer (score 0):

You should first solve the dependencies problem in your project

I think `npm install`

then when all your dependencies are installed you can go.

`ng serve` is for angular right?

did you install `npm install -g @angular/cli`?

You need to give more information if you want a better answer.

Comment: Sorry Im a bit new to all this, When I do npm install I get the same message as above.

Comment: Don't worry, try the way of @CharukaHS said in the comment

Answer (score -1):

This is not a VS Code problem.
You have installed bootstrap but did not install bootstrap dependencies.
You should do the following:

1. run: npm install jquery popper.js
2. update your angular.json the add the newly installed libs:

   ```
    "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
    "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
   ```